# Failed to retrieve data from the database, Database Vendor Code 9421

Tags: sql-server-2005, com, crystal-reports, vbscript, activex

I have a report made in Crystal Reports XI. The report is generated and exported to PDF in visual basic script using COM interface. Generally everything is running smoothly, but in one case generation breaks with error:

**Failed to retrieve data from the database. Details: [Database Vendor Code 9421]**

Database used is **MSSQL 2005** connected over **ODBC** to CR XI. When I am opening report with exactly the same parameters in Designer, everything works fine.

It looks like it is data related, but it is hard to trace since the whole report is pretty sophisticated. Anyway I spent half a day on crawling over Dr. Google and it seems that he has no clue what might be an issue.

Comment: select * from sys.messages where message_id=9421 gives `XML parsing: line %d, character %d, illegal name character` relevant?

Comment: Didn't know that - damn relevant :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you previewed the report in Crystal Reports Developer, did you look at the whole thing? Some custom formulae are not calculated until you actually look at the page.

Try scrolling through the entire report top to bottom.  If your error message pops up halfway through and Crystal refuses to preview the rest of the report, then there's probably some anomaly in your datasource that is tripping up a custom Formula in your Crystal Report.